# What properties does generalized Delaunay triangulation have?

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry, triangulations

Suppose that instead of the usual circle, we pick some other convex set D and make the Delaunay triangulation of a finite planar point set with respect to this set, i.e. connect two points if there is a homothet of D that contains both of them on its boundary and no points inside. If the points are in a general position such that no four fall on the boundary of a homothet of D, then we still obtain a triangulation (plus some infinite face). Can anyone provide a good reference for this statement, how should I cite it? I need it not only for smooth D but also for polygons.

Comment: Cross-posted on CSTheory: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16661/what-properties-does-a-generalized-delaunay-triangulation-have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the earliest reference is this:

> Chew & Drysdale.
>   "Voronoi diagrams based on convex distance functions."
>   1985.
>   ([ACM link](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=323264))

This more recent dissertation at the FernUniversität Hagen may be more directly useful:

> Ma.
>   "Bisectors and Voronoi Diagrams for Convex Distance Functions."
>   2000.
>   ([PDF download](http://www.fernuniversitaethagen.de/imperia/md/content/fakultaetfuermathematikundinformatik/forschung/berichte/bericht_267.pdf))

I extracted this figure from her thesis, p.58:

          
[image: Convex Distance Function]

Google Scholar [finds 42 papers](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=13417898423142145264) post-2000 that cite this dissertation.

Comment: See also R.Klein's book "Concrete and abstract Voronoi diagrams" as well as N.M.Le's papers from 1990s on this subject. 

Comment: @Misha: Not coincidentally, Rolf Klein was Lihong Ma's thesis supervisor! :-) Thanks for the references.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will cite the book, as in the dissertation the simple properties are not stated. (I hope they are in the book, since I could not access it.) Also, here is a direct link to the dissertation: http://www.fernuniversitaethagen.de/imperia/md/content/fakultaetfuermathematikundinformatik/forschung/berichte/bericht_267.pdf

Comment: I managed to access the book, it does not even mention Delaunay triangulations.

Comment: It seems that I have misunderstood the definition of reference-request, thank you for your answer.